# SSRS Report - Control number of rows based on Monitor width and height

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ssrs-2008-r2

Please can anyone help me..

In my ASP.Net MVC 4.0 Project using IDE Visual Studio 2010 SP1, .ASPX Engine, integrated SSRS Report using a third party ( MvcReportViewer ) DLL. Currently the no of rows in the report is fixed as 10. This has been implemented by providing the below expression

```
[ =Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/15) ]
```

in Group On window in Group Properties of General tab. But the requirement is that the reports should auto size based on the users browser window size, i.e. if the window is > than the min size then it should expand accordingly.

Thanks & Regards,
Vishnu

Comment: Fixed the issue by adding a hidden parameter MonitorWidth in the report and from C# Code read the current monitor width and pass as a parameter and on right clicking the Group Properties -> General Tab given the below expression in Group On as below =Switch( 
        Parameters!MonitorHeight.Value= 1050,Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/20),
        Parameters!MonitorHeight.Value= 900,Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/17),
        Parameters!MonitorHeight.Value= 800,Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/15),
        Parameters!MonitorHeight.Value= 768,Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/12)
      )

Comment: if you've answered your own question, why dont you submit it as an answer below and selecting it as best answer. that way people with a similar problem will see it as answered. its actively encouraged see this link - [Can i Answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding a hidden parameter MonitorWidth in the report and from C# Code read the current monitor width and pass as a parameter and on right clicking the Group Properties -> General Tab given the below expression in Group On as below =Switch( Parameters!MonitorHeight.Value= 1050,Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/20), Parameters!MonitorHeight.Value= 900,Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/17), Parameters!MonitorHeight.Value= 800,Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/15), Parameters!MonitorHeight.Value= 768,Ceiling(ROWNUMBER(nothing)/12) )